# How to change column width and height dynamically in amChart JS Radar column series charts?

Tags: amcharts4

I am trying to change series column width and height dynamically in amChart JS Radarchart, but it is not working. Please find the below code and let me know the suggestion.

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());

```
series.columns.template.adapter.add("width", function(text, target, key) {
console.log('hit');
 return am4core.percent(10);
});


series.columns.template.adapter.add("height", function(text, target, key) {
console.log('hit');
 return am4core.percent(10);
});
```